# python update to 2.7.13 on centos

Tags: python, linux, centos

I'm new for linux and python ，yesterday I update my python from 2.6.6 to 2.7.13，but when i finished these command "./configure 、make、make install " ,then run "python“ ,I got "command not found ". thanks for help[image]

Comment: Please tell which centos version are you using?Check out the version using `cat /etc/redhat-release` using root privilege

Comment: the symlinks are missing target, make sure `/usr/local/python2.7.13` is present. did `make` or `make install` return any error message?

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with the answer provided by @holdenweb. Just to add some more details considering for a tyro:

If you need access to a newer version of Python you must compile it yourself and install it side-by-side with the system version.

Here are the steps necessary to install Python 2.7. Execute all the commands below as root. Either log in as root temporarily or use sudo.

#### Install development tools

In order to compile Python you must first install the development tools:
The first one is :

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

You also need a few extra libraries installed before compiling Python or else you will run into problems later when trying to install various packages:

```
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel
```

#### Download, compile and install Python

The --no-check-certificate is optional

```
cd /opt
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-
2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && make altinstall
```

It is important to use `altinstall` instead of `install`, otherwise you will end up with two different versions of Python in the filesystem both named python.

After running the commands above your newly installed Python 2.7 interpreter will be available as `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and the system version of Python 2.6.6 will be available as `/usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2.6.6.`

Answer (score 1):

Now Python is an essential component of many operating systems, the safest rule is *leave the system's Python to the system*, and don't modify it yourself. That way you can be sure you aren't going to interfere with any OS code that depends on a specific version of Python.

If you want some other version of Python to be your own default, install it somewhere like */usr/local/bin* (the default installation for most Linux systems will put it there by default) and then put that directory at the front of your shell's `PATH` to ensure that the `python` command gets your version instead of the system's (which will remain as */usr/bin/python*).

I would recommend that you re-link */usr/bin/python* to point to */usr/bin/python2.6* and then the `PATH` adjustment mentioned above (but in your case adding */usr/local/python2.7.13/bin*, which is where you seem to have installed your updated Python) should be all you need to do.